# how to debug cyclic reference formed due to shared_ptr?

Tags: c++

In an big application I am trying to debug whether cyclic reference due to shared_ptr is present or not?

```
struct A
{
  boost::shared_ptr<C> anC;
};

struct B
{
  boost::shared_ptr<A> anA;
};

struct C
{
  boost::shared_ptr<B> anB;
};
```

Comment: I am surprised you have so many shared pointers to objects than themselves contain shared pointers. Are you using shared pointers ***just for ownership*** or are you using them wherever you need a pointer?

Comment: You can use any tool for memleak detection. I like to use valgrind.